# Where is the git documentation on creating custom subcommands?

Tags: git

It's easy to find documentation on creating git aliases [[1]](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) [[2]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias)  or tutorials on creating custom subcommands (place `git-your-subcommand` on your `$PATH` to enable calling `git your-subcommand`).  However, apart from [the docs on GIT_EXEC_PATH](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables), I can find no documentation on https://git-scm.com about
creating custom subcommands or configuring how they are discovered.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to ask here. They are "discovered" by Git running `git-blah` if you type `git blah`: Git sticks `git --exec-path` into `$PATH` (at the front, actually) and then blindly attempts to run the git-blah command, and if that works, that must be the command. If it fails, there must not be any git-blah after all.

Comment: I'm looking for a URL to official-ish documentation on that process, preferably on git-scm.com, in the git repo, etc. I'm hoping make certain I understand the process, especially all configuration and environment variables involved.

Comment: There isn't much, if anything, official here. The ultimate problem is that Git acquires new config and env settings all the time and the documentation for each is generally fairly scattered. The git-config documentation lists *most* of the formally-adopted config items, but some just get forgotten, e.g., `log.decorate` (added by Linus way back in late 1.x or early 2.x) went undocumented for several years.

Comment: Internally, these things—config strings and environment variables both—are free-form and easily created. If you write your own `git blah`, you can invent your own configuration: you then just have to hope that no one else creates a `git blah` or re-uses your configuration names for something else...

Comment: That's useful: it sounds like I should look through the source. If you can confirm https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/exec-cmd.c is the right place to look, I'll accept that link and your comments on git often missing docs as the answer.

Comment: That's the main bit of code, though there's a bunch of semi-related code for running hooks and filters as well, scattered through other source files. Note also that if Git *can't* find a command, it has a table of built in "known and common" commands and will do a Levenshtein distance calculation to suggest what you might have meant.

Comment: I'd be interested in the semi-related code for hooks.  Do any files come to mind?

Comment: Look for `run_command` and `run_hook` in `run-command.c`; see also Documentation/technical/api-run-command.txt. See also `run_builtin` in `git.c` and `run_shell` in `shell.c`.